# Reply form used in wordpress.com

Tags: plugins, comments, wordpress.com-hosting, comment-form

The reply form that comes originally with wordpress is, well, so big and annoying. While the one that appears on wordpress.com blogs is very elegant and feature-ful.

Does the one used in wordpress.com exist as a pre-made plugin? If so, where can I get it from?

If no however, how can make it by hand, i.e, what are the guidelines to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [Jetpack comments](http://jetpack.me/support/comments/) system. If so, you can install [Jetpack plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/) and then activate the *Comments* module, if it is not activated by default upon plugin activation. After plugin installation, you may also need to connect to your WordPress.com account to enable any (or all) Jetpack features as indicated in [the installation instructions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/installation/).